# Access tocken authentication in express node js (without jwt or passport)

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I'm building a `REST API` server witch generate (or fetch form Db if it already exist ) an access `32 char` token and return it after user logged in , then each time user wants to do something , he/she should send the `access token` in header and what ever she/he wants to do in body , and with each request , server check validity of access token then respond to the user `and token are valid only for a day if user wont sign out`

so I wonder is this a safe method to authenticate users ? is there way to make it more secure ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a middleware into your express app and validate your token there if it's valid one proceed with it other wise return an error response to user.

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

  // check header or url parameters or post parameters for token
  var token = req.headers['x-access-token'];
  // decode token
  if (token) {

    // verifies token 
   var isValidToken = validateToken(token); // function to validate token
    if( isValidToken ){
        next();
     }else{
       // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({ 
        success: false, 
        message: 'No token provided.' 
    });
    }

  } else {

    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({ 
        success: false, 
        message: 'No token provided.' 
    });

  }
});
```